# Passenger 3.0.17 + Nginx 1.2.4 + "Content-Length" Header = 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, http-headers, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

I have just run across an issue where setting `response.headers['Content-Length']` in a Rails 3.2.2 application causes Nginx to throw a "502 Bad Gateway" error.

I have an action in a controller that uses the `send_data` method to send raw JPEG data contained within a variable.  Before, I had a problem with some browsers not downloading the entire image being sent and discovered that no Content-Length header is being sent, so I decided to use the `.bytesize` property of the variable containing the JPEG data as the Content-Length.

This works fine in development (using Unicorn) and there is now a Content-Length header where there wasn't one before, but in production where I'm using Nginx and Passenger, I get the afore-mentioned 502 Bad Gateway.  Also, in the Nginx error log, I see:

```
[error] 30574#0: *1686 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
```

There are no matching entries in the Rails production log, which tells me the application is fine.

I've commented out the line where I set the Content-Length header, and the problem went away.  I'm still testing whether I actually need to send a Content-Length header, but meanwhile, I thought I might post this out of curiosity to see if anyone has any thoughts.

Comment: Looks like someone else has this problem: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/phusion-passenger/lXtIjuf8ct8/discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AHA!  I had to convert the size to a string by adding the `.to_s` method.  So, my final result is

```
response.headers['Content-Length'] = photo_data.bytesize.to_s
send_data photo_data, :type => :jpg, :filename => 'file_name.jpg', :disposition => 'attachment'
```

So, it would seem that it is okay to send the `Content-Length` header on Nginx/Passenger, but Passenger chokes if it's not explicitly a string.